# Chrome Desktop Notifications Not Cancelling

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I have some code which should notify the user, when calling the custom `notify` function, which contains code that listens to notification click events. When clicked, the window should be focus (with `window.focus`), which works, but the notification is not cancelled.

I tried this:

```
var notify = function(title,text) {
    var notification = new Notification(title, {icon:"/images/notify.png", body:text});
    notification.onclick = function() {
        window.focus();
        notification.cancel();
    };
}
```

I also tried this:

```
var notify = function(title,text) {
    var notification = new Notification(title, {icon:"/images/notify.png", body:text});
    notification.onclick = function(current) {
        window.focus();
        current.cancel();
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See tag request for [tag:desktop-notifications] [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316868/tag-request-desktop-notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code instead :

```
var notify = function(title,text) {
    var notification = new Notification(title, {icon:"/images/notify.png", body:text});
    notification.onclick = function() {
        window.focus();
        notification.close();
    };
}
```

You can read more about the .close() method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close).

Cheers,
Fjpackard.